# Unable to play video using asp.net aspx web page

Tags: asp.net, video

Im facing issues with playing a file in asp.net website deployed in server in IIS. It is actually working in the local machine but not working when deployed.
I used below tag in aspx code. I checked all the mime types are configured in IIS.

Any help will be highly appreciated..

```
<video id="vidplayer" autoplay runat="server" controls preload="auto">
<source src="/Files/1.avi" type="video/avi">
</video>
```

Comment: can you download the file you reference in your player src? e.g. webservername:80/Files/1.avi

Comment: Are you encountering some errors? Check the network and browser console to see the problem in production server.

Comment: Hi Harry, Yes when i send the request, it downloads the file locally. But iw ant to play it in webpage.